# Differential 1-form of line

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

This problem is from V.I Arnold's book Mathematics of Classical Mechanics.
Q) Show that every differential 1-form on line is differential of some function

2. Relevant equations
   The differential of any function is
   $$df_{x}(\psi): TM_{x} \rightarrow R$$
3. The attempt at a solution

The tangent to line is line itself. The differential 1-form is $dy-dx=0$. Here I am struct. I don't know how to find out the differential. Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: If you consider $\omega(x)dx$ as the differential form, what can you say about $f(x):=\int_0^x \omega(t)dt$?

Comment: $dy-dx$ is not a differential form on the line, it is a differential form on the plane

Answer (score 1):

$dy-dx$ is not a differential form on $\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ has only one coordinate for every chart you choose.
It is instead a differential form on $\mathbb{R}^2$, where is the differential of 
$f(x,y)=y-x$.

About Arnold's exercise, I would insted prove it in this way:
Let $\omega(x)dx $ be the general differential form on $\mathbb{R}$, where $\omega(x)$ is  $C^{\infty}[\mathbb{R}]$. Then, let $f:=\int_0^x\omega(t)dt$. By definition of differential and by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we obtain that:
$df=\partial_{x}( \int_0^x \omega(t)dt)dx=\omega(x)dx$
QED

Comment: @Abhi7731756 Is there anything wrong  or unclear with the answer?